# Instant Payment Notification

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to have VIP buy button, i have button with text box (generated from PP) and this code(its not full, its classic IPN code what paypal give u in tutorial, i showing just part with changes):

```
...........
    // STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        // The IPN is verified, process it:
        // check whether the payment_status is Completed 
        // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
        // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
        // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
        // process the notification

        // assign posted variables to local variables
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name']; 
        $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
        $player_indentificator = $_POST["player_id"];
        mail("ales.nezbeda@gmail.com", "TEST", $player_indentificator)

        // IPN message values depend upon the type of notification sent.
        // To loop through the &_POST array and print the NV pairs to the screen:
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
          echo $key." = ". $value."<br>";
        }
    } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
        echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";
    }
    ?>
```

But when i pay, i dont recieve that email. Why? Maybe im doing something wrong and maybe terribly wrong.

Comment: Do you ever execute the 'mail()' line in your code? Does it get any errors? Do you check for them? You haven't provided enough information.

Comment: That's not a security breach at all.  IPN makes a call back to PayPal to verify data actually came from them.  Your code logic can easily discard or log any unverified IPN's that somebody may hit it with. I typically ask people their IPN URL when they're having troubles, too, so I can hit it myself and see what result I get.  That helps troubleshoot.

Comment: @EJP Could you let me know what is the security breach  here just by knowing the IPN URL?

Answer (score 0):

1)  You need to make sure IPN is enabled in the account you're working with.  If you're working on the sandbox then you need to make sure IPN is enabled in that account profile and pointing to the IPN URL you'd like to use.  If you're working with a live account you do the same thing in that live account.  I often see people who have it setup in one place but then they're submitting a payment to the other.  Make sure that's not the case here.

2)  The profile could be overridden using the notify_url parameter in HTML buttons or the NotifyURL parameter in API requests.  Are you using either of these methods?  If so, double check the value of the URL so you can ensure you're hitting the correct URL.

3)  If you've verified the above then you need to look at your IPN History in the PayPal account you're working with.  It will show you if it's sending IPN's or not when transactions occur, and it will also display the result code it got back from your server when it POSTed the IPN.

If you don't see any logs in the IPN History then you need to double check what I mentioned above because it's simply not configured to send for some reason.

If you do see logs in there but they show something other than 200 for the result then that means you have a problem with the IPN script that needs to be resolved. Could be a syntax error or something silly like that.  Looking at your web server logs would help you determine the error.

Another thing I like to do is create a simple HTML form with a bunch of hidden fields that represent what I would expect to get from an IPN.  Set the action of the form to your IPN URL and then you can load this up in a browser and submit it to see the result on screen. This can greatly improve your ability to find and fix problems.  Once you get everything working as expected that way you can rest assured it'll work the same way when real IPN's are sent.

Just keep in mind that when testing that way the data is not coming from PayPal so it will not verify.  You'll need to make sure your code logic is setup to handle that accordingly.  I like to log unverified IPN's and send myself an email that I need to look into the transaction since it was unverified.